# Excel sheet-related code added from another workbook disappears after closing and reopening the file

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel workbook of xlsb format (let's call it "Child-workbook") automatically generated by another excel workbook ("Parent-workbook").
This so called "Child Workbook" has some sheets, containing graphs. I want these sheets to have a code that runs each time the user selects the sheet, and I want the "Parent Workbook" to transfer that code to "Child-workbook". The transfer has been done succesfully, the module does appear in the Child workbook's project until I close it (of course I save it before that...).

[Here is an image of how it looks like after saving but before closing "Child.xlsb".](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rNl3d.jpg)

My problem is that when I reopen the Child workbook, the module is still there though, but its content is completely gone, it's empty.

[Here is an image of how it looks like after saving, closing and reopening it.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ArYae.jpg)

Any advice?

```
Sub TransferModule()

    Const MODULE_NAME    As String = "DiagramMakro"      
    Dim MODULEFILE       As String
    MODULEFILE = "C:\Modul.txt"

   Workbooks("Parent.xlsm").VBProject.VBComponents(MODULE_NAME).Export MODULEFILE

    For i = 1 To Workbooks("CHILD.xlsb").Sheets.Count
        If Workbooks("CHILD.xlsb").Worksheets(i).Name Like "Diagram*" Then
            Workbooks("CHILD.xlsb").Worksheets(i).Activate            
            Workbooks("CHILD.xlsb").VBProject.VBComponents(ActiveSheet.CodeName).Name = MODULE_NAME
            Workbooks("CHILD.xlsb").VBProject.VBComponents.Item("CHILD.xlsb").CodeModule.AddFromFile (MODULEFILE)
        End If
    Next i
   Kill MODULEFILE

End Sub
```

And here is the Module to transfer:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Activate()
    Dim myChart As Chart
    Dim mySeries As SeriesCollection
    Set myChart = ActiveSheet.ChartObjects(1).Chart
    Set mySeries = myChart.SeriesCollection
    For i = 3 To mySeries.Count
        mySeries.Item(i).Format.Line.Visible = msoFalse
    Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: Sorry, I'm new here, maybe that's why I cannot find the following additional information I needed to specify during the process of creating a post: I already tried to use xlsm format instead of xlsb, but it did not lead to any success.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe problems with txt file

Try read [this first](https://www.bettersolutions.com/vba/visual-basic-editor/extensibility-object-model.htm) and run [CreateEventProcedure](https://www.bettersolutions.com/vba/visual-basic-editor/extensibility-sample-code.htm)

[VBA Editor Constants](https://www.bettersolutions.com/vba/enumerations/vba-editor-constants.htm)

Comment: I did and I appreciate the links you sent. They are very useful. However I could not figure out yet, what the problem could be. I keep examining and investigating.